# Call variables from a file

Tags: file, variables, store, cat

I need to retrieve variables that have been stored in a file. I am capturing the variable for an install of prostgress and some other programs. Here is the script that I am using to create the variables.sh file at the beginning of the install script.

#!/bin/bash
   # init

function pause(){
   read -p "$*"
   }

echo " Enter db user name "
   echo " "

```
read dbuser

echo " "
echo " Enter name of database  "
echo " "

read dbname

echo " "
echo " Enter db password "
echo "  "

read pws

echo " "
echo " Enter Port Number "
echo " "

read port

echo " "
echo " Enter URL i.e. my.hospital.com:8191 or 78.12.156.234:8191 "
echo " "

read url

cat > variables.dat << EOF

dbuser=$dbuser
dbname=$dbname
pws=$pws
port=$port
url=$url

EOF

if [ -f variables.sh ];

   then 
     echo " Data stored ready for next phase "

   else 

     echo " Data not stored - exit program start again "
     echo " "
     pause " Press [CTL] [Z] to exit the program now "

fi

chmod +x variables.sh

exit
```

During the execution of the other modules that I have written. I want to be able to open or call the variables file and pass variables to the executing script. So my pac-install.sh will include the variables.sh file and pass it's contents to the pac-install.sh script and be able to use the dbuser=$dbuser. I hope this is more concrete.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Perhaps something quick and dirty? `cat file | grep a= | sed s/a=//`

Comment: Austin that is quick and gets me the variable but how to can I pass that variable to read?

Comment: Sorry I meant how do I pass the variable to the read command?

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example of what "capture the variable for an install process" means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the bash **source** command is what you are looking for?

If the file *variables.sh* contains the lines

```
dbuser="the user"
dbname="the name"
...
```

then you can execute

```
source variables.sh
```

from a bash shell script to read and execute the commands from this file. This will assign the values to the shell variables `$dbuser`, `$dbname` etc.

Note that you should enclose the values in quotation marks if they contain spaces.

**Example** how to read back the variables from the file:

```
#!/bin/bash

source variables.sh
echo "dbuser=$dbuser"
echo "dbname=$dbname"
```

Comment: Could you post an example of how the read and execute would be done? I have included the variables.sh in the script but can't get the pass the info to the runing script. Thank you!

Comment: @user1794918: I have added an example to my answer.